# latexdiff doesn't mark changes in bibliography (BibTeX)

Tags: bibtex, latexdiff, achemso

I'm using latexdiff to show changes between versions of an article written with the `achemso` package, but it doesn't seem to be able to highlight changes within the bibliography (including added `\bibnote{}` commands and added citations).  `BibTeX` is used to produce the bibliography with the `\bibliography{filename}` command in the main `LaTeX` file.  I'm using `latexdiff` in the following way:

```
latexdiff --subtype=COLOR old.tex new.tex > diff.tex
```

The resulting `LaTeX` file does mark the new citation numbers which appear in the text, but doesn't highlight anything in the bibliography.  In there a convenient way to have `latexdiff` mark changes in the bibliography?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You have to use `latexdiff` directly on the bbl files.  So just execute

`latexdiff old.bbl new.bbl > diff.bbl`

and then execute `(pdf)latex diff.tex`.  This generally works well with (author,year) style of citations, but I have not tried it with numbered styles.

For the `bibnote` command you probably have to use `--append-textcmd` option

`latexdiff --append-textcmd=bibnote ...`

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  I was just hoping that there was a way to do this whereby the markup could be handled in the main `LaTeX` file so that I wouldn't have to call `latexdiff` multiple times.  It's also a bit inconvenient to have to prevent TeXworks from recompiling the `bbl` file when compiling the output of `latexdiff`.  Alas, sometimes the long way is the only way.

Comment: I just checked and yes this works with numbered styles as well.  For, example, there are not false positives when the numbers shifts.