# Latexdiff doesn't make changes in bibliography(natbib) in Overleaf

Tags: bibliographies, natbib, overleaf, latexdiff

I am using the following commands to make a PDF file which shows changes between two .tex files. It works nicely but not for the bibliography.

Please find the commands in the overleaf below for generating the pdf with differences:

\RequirePackage{shellesc}
\ShellEscape{latexdiff main2.tex main.tex > diff_result.tex}
\input{diff_result}
\documentclass{dummy}

Can someone suggest how I can also make overleaf show the changes in the bibliography?

Thanks.

Comment: (a) It probably will depend on how you include the bibliography. Are you using `bibtex`? (b) I am unsure what you mean by "show the changes in the bibliography", can you describe in more detail what is the desired behavior?

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/172094/119

Comment: Outside Overleaf, there are two options of marking up changes in the bibliography.  1) Run latexdiff separately on the bbl files (as indicated in the link posted by @WillieWong ) or (2) use the --flatten option which, however, also needs the bbl files for old and new files to be present. 
Within latexdiff the intermediate files (bbl, aux etc) are not accessible to user to my knowledge, but maybe actually accessible to \ShellEscape. Maybe you can contact Overleaf directly to enquire how to access intermediate files; in my experience their support is very responsive and helpful.